# Redirect user if username matches my cookie token? PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, session, cookies

I used to have cookies which were unencrypted so the following code worked fine:

```
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
if ( $username == $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) { 
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=\"0; URL='/profile.html'\">";
} else {
```

However now my cookies work on a MySQL encrypted cookie token basis. I need to basically detect if the username/profile you're trying to access is the same as the one matching your cookie token then it redirects you to /profile.html. I'm not quite sure how to do it? Any suggestions or  help? I've looked online but can't seem to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
if ( $username == $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) { 
  header('Location: /profile.html');

...
```

Comment: That would also work but the trouble is the cookie loggedin isn't the username anymore. It's encrypted code :/ So I need a way of detecting if the encrypted code matches the encrypted code stored in the same entry of the database as the username and if they match then redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
if ( $username == $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) { 
header("Location: /profile.html");
}
```

And dont forget start session with this function : session_start();

Comment: That would also work but the trouble is the cookie loggedin isn't the username anymore. It's encrypted code :/ So I need a way of detecting if the encrypted code matches the encrypted code stored in the same entry of the database as the username and if they match then redirect.

Comment: Okay than you can check with coding use your variable. For example
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
if ( md5($username) == $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) { 
header("Location: /profile.html");
}

Comment: I usually use md5 so i put there md5. You will put there which coding you use

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the cookie session is a random cookie token stored into the MySQL 'members' table. Each registered user has a 'cstoken' column with a random generated token each time they login :(